# Using the PHP built-in server in production

Tags: php, security, webserver

I was recently curious about PHP 5.4's built-in webserver. On the surface it seems as though, while rather barebones, with enough work it could be possible to distribute PHP applications that traditionally depend on a separate web server, like WordPress, as standalone scripts that you could just run with `php -S localhost:80 app.php` (or, more likely, `'./wordpress.sh'`). They might even ship with their own PHP interpreter that has all the features the application needs, which would obviate the need for targeting many different versions of the language.

It's re-inventing the wheel somewhat, but it would certainly increase portability and reduce complexity for the end user.

However, I saw the following on the [documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php):

> This web server was designed to aid application development. It may also be useful for testing purposes or for application demonstrations that are run in controlled environments. It is not intended to be a full-featured web server. It should not be used on a public network.

This would obviously refer to issues like proper filesystem security and serving the correct HTTP headers, which can be worked through. However, is there more to it? Are there inherent security concerns and/or technical limitations with using PHP's built-in web server in a production environment that can't be worked around? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I can think of plenty of operational issues why you wouldn't want to do this:

- Logging
- Rewrites
- Throttling
- Efficiency (not tested, but I'm guessing Nginx is a lot faster than PHP's built-in non-optimized server)
- Integration with anything else you have that extends Nginx, Apache, and IIS (things like New Relic)

However, there is a solution where you get most of the benefit of running PHP with its built-in web server while getting most of the benefit of running a web server out front.  That is, you could use a server like Nginx as a reverse proxy to PHP's built-in web server.  In this situation, HTTP becomes a replacement for FastCGI, analogous to common usages of the built-in HTTP server in Node.js applications.

Now, I can't speak to the specifics of the warning in the documentation as I am not one of the PHP authors.  If it were me, I'd not run PHP alone for the reasons above, but I *might* consider running it behind a real web server like Nginx.  For me though, setting up PHP with PHP-FPM and what not isn't that difficult, and I'll take that over guessing at the seaworthiness of a built-in server that is documented to be for testing only.

Comment: you can use logging and rewrites with the built-in webserver. However, efficiency and security might be problematic compared to real webservers though...

Answer (score 15):

The problem with PHP's built-in web server is that it is **single threaded**!

That has performance and security implications. Performance implications obviously are that only one user can be served at a time (until one request finishes, another can not start).

Security implications are that it's pretty easy to DOS that server, using a simple open socket that sends tiny amounts of data (similar to Slow Loris).

It's useful for simple, one-page, non-interactive applications that have no risk of denial of service.

Comment: Since PHP 7.4 (2019) it's now multi-threaded via the `PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS` env option

Answer (score 3):

PHP's built in server only supports HTTP/1.0, which means clients have to make a new TCP/IP connection for every request. This is very slow.

Comment: I don't think this answer is up to date. I ran with version 7.2.5 like this php -S localhost:8080 &. curl -I localhost:8080 and it said HTTP/1.1. Also I load tested it with github.com/ijt/hammer (hit up arrow a few times) and it did thousands of QPS at least on hello world. Maybe it's not production ready for some other reason, but this is not the reason.